# Django request.session not passed within views

Tags: reactjs, django, session, django-rest-framework

I have made a React-Django application. The front-end takes aws credentials and saves it in a session successfully. The verification and session storage occurs in one API view (LoginVerification), and I'm trying to access the session data in another API view (BucketSize).

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
class LoginVerification(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    

    @staticmethod
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(request):
        from .awsdata.generalstats.login_verification import verify_aws_credentials

        # Get data from the POST request
        data = request.data
        aws_access_key = data.get('accessKey', '')
        aws_secret_key = data.get('secretKey', '')
        aws_region = data.get('region', '')
        aws_bucket = data.get('bucket', '')

        aws_verification = verify_aws_credentials(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, aws_region, aws_bucket)
        if aws_verification == 'Connected':
            request.session['aws_credentials'] = {
                'aws_access_key': aws_access_key,
                'aws_secret_key': aws_secret_key,
                'aws_region': aws_region,
                'aws_bucket': aws_bucket,
            }
            request.session.modified = True
            request.session.save()
            print("session items verification --- ",request.session.items())
            print(f"LoginVerification session key: {request.session.session_key}")
            print(aws_verification)
        else:
            pass

        

        return Response({"verification": aws_verification})
```

Output -

> session items verification ---  dict_items([('aws_credentials', {'aws_access_key': 'ARPCUF2HGDHVVS', 'aws_secret_key': 'riF1LRP266RycuZFO7hYV', 'aws_region': 'eu-central-1', 'aws_bucket': 'BUCKETNAME'})])

However when I try to print it out in my other view(BucketSize), the output is an empty dictionary

```
class BucketSize(APIView):
    

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        
        print("session items --- ",request.session.get("aws_access_key"))
        
      
            return Response({'status': 'success', 'bucketsize': bucketsize, 'unit': unit})
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'status': 'error', 'error': str(e)})
```

I have CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True in my Django settings and withCredentials: true in my axios request. My SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is set to True, and SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY is set to False because I'm testing on localhost without HTTPS.

This is my settings.py --

```
# Application definition
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True  

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'server',
    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    

]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {"DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
    "rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny"]}

# settings.
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ["http://localhost:3000"]
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'
```

Why is the session data not persisting across the different views? How can I ensure the session data set in LoginVerification is accessible in BucketSize?